# Docker: cross stack communication via bridge network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-machine

Suppose I have 2 yml files which I run via docker-compose up.

efk.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  fluentd:
    
    image: fluentd
     ...
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/etc:/fluentd/etc
    depends_on:
     - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
   
    

  elasticsearch:
   
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.3 

    expose:
      - 9200
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
   
  kibana:
  ...
    logging:
       driver: "fluentd"
       options:
         fluentd-address: localhost:24224
         tag: micro.kibana
```

(I've omit some irrelevant part, I need just logging)

app.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ..
    logging:
       driver: "fluentd"
       options:
         fluentd-address: fluentd:24224
        # fluentd-async-connect: "true"
         tag: micro.db
    networks:
      - default  

  app:       
    ...
    logging:
       driver: "fluentd"
       options:
         fluentd-address: fluentd:24224
        # fluentd-async-connect: "true"
         tag: micro.php-fpm
    networks:
      - default   
    

 
networks:
  default:
    external: 
      name: efk_default
```

I plan to launch efk stack initially like

```
 docker-compose -p efk -f efk.yml up -d
```

and then:

```
docker-compose -p app -f app.yml up -d
```

I assume that bridge network efk_default will be created and I can access it from app stack (see app.yml for details). But app stack couldn't resolve fluentd:24224 in bridge network, I get following error on command above for app:

*ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp: lookup fluentd: Temporary failure in name resolution
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.*

If I use smth dumb like localhost:24224 just to make it launch, via docker network inspect I can see all containers in one network. I've tried to use ip addr. in bridged network but it didn't work either.

Is it possible to have common logging service within this configuration?
If yes, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I try, it works like you'd expect and I can reach the containers in the efk file from the containers in the app file.

Comment: @HansKilian: You launch stacks via docker-compose up?

Comment: Yes. I launched an nginx container in one stack and a debian in the other. Then installed wget in debian and checked that it could DNS resolve the service name of the nginx container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to test it:

compose1.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: nginx
```

compose2.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app2:
    image: curlimages/curl
    command: http://app1/

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: efk_default
```

Commands run:

```
docker-compose -p efk -f compose1.yml up -d
docker-compose -p efk -f compose2.yml up
```

and it outputs the Nginx welcome page.

Comment: It definitely works when services in same bridged network. It seems in my case I have docker host logging issues rather than name resolving.